# How can I iterate through a list of dictionaries and extract a subset of values in Python using loops?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, subset

**Iterate through a list of dictionaries  to get subset**

I have a python list as follows:

data_list is equivalent to values key
in a dictionary object which is a list of items

```
 "values": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "center code here": 3,
            "d": 4,
        },
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3
            "d": 4,
        },
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3
            "d": 4,
        },
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3
            "d": 4,

        }
    ]
```

I also have another list that holds the values i want

```
listx = [a,b]
```

This is what i tried :

```
 listx = [a,b]
 dict2 = {}    
                
 for d in data_list:     
     for v,x in d.items(): 
          if v in listx:
              dict2[v] = (x)
                
 print(len(dict2))
```

I get 12 which is the number of items in one dictionary. It doesn't iterate over the other dictionaries?
Can anyone help ?

My goal is to be able to create a subset of this list with the following values :

```
     "values": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2
        },
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2
        },
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2
        },
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2

        }
    ]
```

Can anyone help me here ? What am i doping wrong?

Comment: Does `data_list` really contain a string? `for d in data_list:` iterates over the characters in the string. Then `d.items()` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple list comprehension to filter the values:

```py
values = [
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4,
    },
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4,
    },
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4,
    },
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4,
    },
]

listx = ["a", "b"]

values_filtered = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in listx} for d in values]
print(values_filtered)
```

Prints:

```
[
 {"a": 1, "b": 2}, 
 {"a": 1, "b": 2}, 
 {"a": 1, "b": 2}, 
 {"a": 1, "b": 2}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
listx = ["a", "b"]
subset = []

for d in data_list:
    subset_dict = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key in listx:
            subset_dict[key] = value
    subset.append(subset_dict)

print(subset)
```

Output:

```py
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

*Or* you can use `itemgetter`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

listx = ["a", "b"]
subset = [dict(zip(listx, itemgetter(*listx)(d))) for d in data_list]
print(subset)
```